# In rails is there a way to get the header info returned from a Net::HTTP call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, header

I am uploading products to a back end system that takes HTTP/XML  Everything is working perfectly... I send the product, I get back a stunning amount of XML as a result.
Stunning in that it contains almost nothing.  A few tags that contain other tags, that contain success.

Sure enough info right??  :)

A date stamp would be good, and is required by my boss.  I need a way to record when the "success" was sent out. Not when I received it, because my time-stamp might not match the servers time-stamp.

I've used the SOAP-UI tool to send the original XML because its allows me to alter the XML rather quickly and test if it's valid.  In the raw response, I see the server that sent the response, and the time.

Here's what the raw response has in it.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 04 Jul 2013 23:46:00 GMT
Server: Apache
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=XXXXXXXXXX; expires=Fri, 05-Jul-2013 00:01:00 GMT; path=/enterprise11301; domain=XXXX.net.nz; secure; HttpOnly
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: CUSTOMER=deleted; expires=Wed, 04-Jul-2012 23:45:59 GMT; path=/enterprise11301; domain=staging.XX.net.nz; secure; httponly
Set-Cookie: CUSTOMER_INFO=deleted; expires=Wed, 04-Jul-2012 23:45:59 GMT; path=/enterprise11301; domain=staging.XX.net.nz; secure; httponly
Set-Cookie: CUSTOMER_AUTH=deleted; expires=Wed, 04-Jul-2012 23:45:59 GMT; path=/enterprise11301; domain=staging.XX.net.nz; secure; httponly
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 282
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
```

So I want that info when I send the exact same thing in ruby/rails 
Here's my code for sending, and getting the response.

```
 url = URI.parse( @credentials[:endpoint] );
 http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
 http.use_ssl = false
 http.verify_mode = 0
 request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url.path);
 request.body = @xml    
 response = http.start { |http_runner| http_runner.request( request ) }
```

So any thoughts on how to expand this to gain access to the RAW?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay.. I did a pile of digging and eventually just called :methods on the response.

```
raise response.to_hash.to_xml   #And poof I see what I'm looking for...
```